# Different Link in context menu depending on ImageView Clicked

Tags: java, android, contextmenu

I have an activity that has crests of different teams, when one is clicked a context menu is displayed with the possibility of opening the teams wikipedia page on the browser. I managed to create a different context menu depending on the ImageView but have no idea how I'm going to pass the link. Any help ?

Context_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item
        android:id="@+id/link"
        android:title="Open Wikipedia Page"
        />
</menu>
```

Teams Class

```
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu,v,menuInfo);
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.atalanta:
                    menu.setHeaderTitle("Atalanta");
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu,menu);
                    break;
                case R.id.bologna:
                    menu.setHeaderTitle("Bologna");
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu,menu);
                    break;
                case R.id.cagliari:
                    menu.setHeaderTitle("Cagliari");
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu,menu);
                    break;
                case R.id.chievo:
                    menu.setHeaderTitle("Chievo");
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu,menu);
                    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to set the context menu's header title based on where do your code get in the `switch` block, you are able also to set a `String` variable to the link. After the `switch`, you can create a new `Intent`, pass the link to it, then start it. All of this should look like below:

```
String link = "";
//...
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.atlanta:
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Atalanta");
        link = "https://whateveryouwant.com"
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu,menu);
        break;
    //do this with every case
}
//...
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(link));
startActivity(i);
```